# If i'm using ng-route, how do I link up my controller? Do i have to declare 'script' everywhere?

Tags: angularjs

If i'm using ng-route, how do I link up my controller? Do i have to declare 'script' everywhere?

Let's say I have 10 controllers and i'm using ng-route. Do I have to do

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>  
... more controllers
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain technologies for lazy loading, like require.js
But there is nothing wrong with adding the controllers to index.html
Both options have pros/cons.

Have a look here: [AngularJS, requireJS and ngRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203890/angularjs-requirejs-and-ngroute)

Comment: okay. i thought it was bad practice to use require with angular.

Comment: @runners3431: not at all - angular2 has its own mechanism (based on systemjs)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, just remember to minimize those files into a single file in production for better performance. If you are using Angular 1.X it's not simple to handle lazy loading angular scripts files (controller, services etc). Declare all calls into your layout file.

```
// development 
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script> 

// production
<script src="controllers.min.js"></script>
```

For minification i use Grunt/NodeJS.